# search by subproces in dir and return non-zero error

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess

i want to make a program to search all my pc and make list of result , so first of all i can not search all partition together and have to use `os.chdir("")` on the other hand when some Suffix dose not exit in it make a error and stop program.

My code:

```
os.chdir("E:\\")
txt = subprocess.check_output("dir /S /B *.txt" , shell=True).decode().split()
dll = subprocess.check_output("dir /S /B *.dll" , shell=True).decode().split()
png = subprocess.check_output("dir /S /B *.png" , shell=True).decode().split()
gif = subprocess.check_output("dir /S /B *.gif" , shell=True).decode().split()
tlb = subprocess.check_output("dir /S /B *.tlb" , shell=True).decode().split()

ALL = txt + dll + png + gif + tlb
```

And result:

```
File Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\code\lock\debug.py", line 12, in <module>
    png = subprocess.check_output("dir /S /B *.png" , shell=True).decode().split()
  File "C:\Users\81332668\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\81332668\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'dir /S /B *.png' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

What sould i do to debug and improve my code!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're using `check_output()` which will raise an exception if the command returns a non-zero error code, and dir does that if it finds no files that match.

You should use `getoutput` if you don't care about that.

However, there's really no need to shell out to `dir` 5 times here – just use `os.walk()`:

```
import os
EXTENSIONS = {".txt", ".dll", ".png", ".gif", ".tlb"}
found_files = []
for dirname, dirpaths, filenames in os.walk("E:\\"):
    for filename in filenames:
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]
        if ext in EXTENSIONS:
            found_files.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

for file in found_files:
    print(file)
```

Comment: dude your code work but i want to put all result in one list although your code put every result in each list , may u improve that too?

Comment: @m7.arman My code didn't put anything in any lists, but it does now.

Comment: in last line i must print found_file . Any way thank you u solve my bug

Comment: dude i have a question in the first for ring i can code like this:.. os.walk("E:\\"and"C:\\"):    I try taht i think make error as just reply a result

Comment: If you need multiple roots, you will need to add another loop for that: `for root in ("E:\\", "C:\\"): for dirname, dirpaths, filenames in os.walk(root):` etc.